# Using MPI_Wait before a new MPI_Isend

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to use MPI_Wait to block an MPI_Isend that may or may not have been called before, but it doesn't seem to be blocking the next MPI_Isend.

Basically if an MPI_Isend has been called before and not been received, then I want to wait until it gets received. And after that call a new MPI_Isend. Every process should always probe for incoming messages and receive them dynamically.

```
for (time_stamp=0; time_stamp<time_max; time_stamp++) { // for each time stamp

    // Probe for incoming particles from any process
    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &statRec);

    // Receive particles from a process
    if(flag){
        std::cout << "Recieved from rank: " << statRec.MPI_SOURCE <<  "\n";
        int recCount{};
        MPI_Get_count(&statRec, MPI_Particle, &recCount);
        Particle *recbuf = new Particle[recCount];
        MPI_Recv(recbuf, recCount, MPI_Particle, statRec.MPI_SOURCE, statRec.MPI_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        for(int i=0; i<recCount; i++)
            Particles.emplace_back(recbuf[i]);

        delete[] recbuf;
    }

    int n = (int)Particles.size(), totalp = 0;
    MPI_Reduce(&n, &totalp,  1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(rank == root)
        std::cout << "Total particles "  << totalp << "\n";

    /* Do particle operations, put them in sendlists
       and delete them from this ranks own particle list.... */

    // Send to another process
    if(!sendParticles.empty()) {
        MPI_Wait(&req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        std::cout << "Sending from rank " << rank << "... \n" ;
        delete[] sendBuf;
        sendcount = static_cast<int>(sendParticles.size());
        sendBuf = new Particle[sendcount];
        for(int i=0; i<sendParticles.size(); i++)
            sendBup[i] = sendParticles[i];

        MPI_Isend(sendBuf, sendcount, MPI_Particle, some_other_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
    }
}
```

Output:
Total particles 1000
Sending from rank 1...
Sending from rank 0...
Total particles 998
Sending from rank 1...
Sending from rank 0...
Recieved from rank: 1
Total particles 994
Sending from rank 1...
Recieved from rank: 0
Sending from rank 0...
Recieved from rank: 1
Total particles 993
Sending from rank 0...
Recieved from rank: 1
Total particles 993
Sending from rank 1...
Sending from rank 0...

As you can see, it tries to send 2 times in a row for both processes, ignoring the MPI_Wait. It also seems to decrease to total number of particles all the time, I'm guessing some get lost since it overwrites the sendbuffer because it doesn't wait.

(Made some edits to code to make it more readable)

Answer (score 1):

If you call `MPI_Wait()` on a request coming from a previous `MPI_ISend()`, then it will block until the send buffer can be reused.

From a very down to earth point of view, it will return immediatly if the message is short enough, and hang until a matching receive is posted otherwise.
(*short enough* depends on your MPI library, your interconnect and other factors. note you should never take for granted that `MPI_Wait()` will return immediately with small messages).

Your description suggests you need to replace `MPI_Isend()` with `MPI_Issend()`.

Note the standard only mandates `MPI_Wait()` returns when a matching receive is posted, so stricly speaking, it might return before the message is fully received by the remote peer.